# c++ with ndk platform error help '_IOR' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ioctl

anyone can tell me why i get this error when compile cpp code with ndk:

```
C:/ndk/samples/fmservice/src/jni/JFmRxNative.cpp:304:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
C:/ndk/samples/fmservice/src/jni/JFmRxNative.cpp:304:24: error: '_IOR' was not declared in this scope
line 304 : res = ioctl(radio_fd,VIDIOC_QUERYCAP,&cap); character 24: VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
```

nd i used C:\ndk\platforms\android-14 files

Answer (score 2):

seams i need to add this `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`